# python telegram bot: why are digits a link to phone number?

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

Sending text/markdown with **Python-Telegram-Bot**, all digit groups are rendered as **links to phone numbers** like in

[image: test image]

Clicking on **12345** it jumps to the phone call keyboard. How can I avoid this behavior, rendering **12345 as normal text** (not a link)?

I went through the documentation but cannot find any reference to this particular issue.

This is the test code:

```py
import telegram
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler

TOKEN="token_here"

def start_function(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text("Test 12345", parse_mode=telegram.ParseMode.MARKDOWN)

bot = telegram.Bot(token=TOKEN)
updater = Updater(token=TOKEN, use_context=True)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start_function))
updater.start_polling()
```

Any pointer to docs or examples is welcome. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try html formatting
https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Code-snippets#post-a-text-message-with-html-formatting

Comment: It is the same with HTML too...
In the desktop app it is read as text, in Android as a link.

Comment: Try adding <span><! your text></span> with html

Comment: No way: <span> is not recognized.
`telegram.error.BadRequest: Can't parse entities: unsupported start tag "span"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MarkDown**

Wrap the number in ``` `` ```(backtick);

```
Test: `12345`
```

**HTML**

Wrap the number in a `<code></code>` block;

```
Test: <code>12345</code>
```

---

*MarkDown* example (first witout ``` `` ```, second request;):

```
&text=Test: `12345`&parse_mode=MarkDown
```

[image]

Comment: Nice trick! The font is a little different from the standard one, but the result is what I need. Thank you.

Where did you find it? Is it in the docs?

Comment: @AlexPoca Yea, font's differents per devices so you'll never now for sure how it looks ;) I've used the code block (3 backticks) quite some time, this 'inline code' is described in the [markdown docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#markdown-style).